# Determining coordinates of quadratic Bezier curve control point given start and end coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, bezier

I'm working with JavaScript/HTML5 Canvas to recreate an old DOS game, and I'm having trouble with trajectories. I know I'll be using quadraticCurveTo() to draw a quadratic Bezier curve to the canvas, but I'm not great with math, and I'm having trouble determining the coordinates of the control point.

I have the starting coordinates, and I've been able to calculate the distance traveled by the projectile, so I also have the ending coordinates.

So, with these two points, as well as the initial angle, velocity, and gravity, how can I determine the coordinates of the control point?

Disclaimer: This is for my university coursework, and I'd like to stay away from jQuery and other such frameworks

Comment: Um, trajectories are quadratic curves, not quadratic Beziers. You're using the wrong curve.

Comment: I recognize that, but I don't believe that the canvas 2D context gives a good method besides quadraticCurveTo() for drawing quadratic curves that have different starting and ending heights. I could certainly be wrong though, and if I am, some sample code would be awesome :)

Comment: quadraticCurveTo does not draw quadratic curves. It draws curves that are quadratically-parameterized. The initial and terminal angles are the line segment from the initial point to the control point and the control point to the final point. That completely determines the control point, so you don't have control over the velocity or acceleration.

Comment: Ok, so what would you suggest as a solution? arcTo() or something?

Comment: Approximate the curve with line segments or points. Since you are emulating a DOS game, and DOS screen resolution is pretty blocky anyway, the jaggedness won't be noticeable.